# contructing API with PHP JSON

Tags: php, json

I am dealing with API between websites, and it doesn't work well. :/ (I am php beginner)

Via `api_login()`, I send `$data` to fakeapiurl.com/Zone and get the zone data in `$zone`.

```
function api_login () {
    $data = [
        'COM_CODE' => '1234',
        'USER_ID'  => 'user',
    );

    $ch      = curl_init("https://fakeapiurl.com/Zone");
    $payload = json_encode($data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($result);

    $zone = $json->Data->ZONE;
}
```

I don't know whether the line below is right. My intention is to group the zone data in the `$data` array.

```
array_push($data, $zone);
```

My hope is to make `$data` just like this:

```
$data = array(
    'COM_CODE' => '1234',
    'USER_ID'  => 'user',
    'ZONE'     => $zone,
);
```

Only when the `$data` is set, I can login and get the session id.

```
$ch      = curl_init("https://fakeapiurl.com/Login");
$payload = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);

$session_id = $json->Data->SESSION_ID;

return $session_id;
```

I've searched for php, json related pages, but couldn't find why my code doesn't work. Your help will be so much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know whether the line below is right. My intention is to group the zone data in the `$data` array.
>
> ```
> array_push($data, $zone);
> ```
>
> My hope is to make `$data` just like this:
>
> ```
> $data = array(
>     'COM_CODE' => '1234',
>     'USER_ID'  => 'user',
>     'ZONE'     => $zone,
> );
> ```

To do this try

```
$data['ZONE'] = $zone;
```

Instead of `array_push($data, $zone);`. (Your solution wouldn't set the `"ZONE"` key on `$zone`).

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge! It was helpful.

Comment: No problem @DahnHwang I'm glad I could help you.